# PrintWriter not writing all Strings

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, printwriter

I have a very annoying problem when I'm using PrintWriters.
I have 6 threads running with each one 2 separate PrintWriters writing tmp0AAA and tmp0BBB, tmp1AAA, tmp1BBB etc.. (...tmp5AAA, tmp5BBB)

At the end of my run() method I get 2 ArrayLists with size of let's say 1200 and 800.

```
for(String s : AAA_array){ // AAA_array size 1200
    this.printerAAA.println(s);
}
for(String s : BBB_array){ // BBB_array size 800
    this.printerBBB.println(s);
}
```

But when I check the size of the 2 files generated I see only 1000 lines for the first tmp file and 700 for the second one (example values, I don't have the exact values in mind)

Any idea why I'm loosing strings?

Comment: Do your threads write directly to the file or do they go through some other layer?

Comment: Are you closing the print writers afterwards? Can you create a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yes I close the 2 printwriters, I'll create that short program.

Comment: @npinti yes I write directly to the file

Comment: [edit] Actually I forgot one close()... thanks @JonSkeet....

Comment: And this is why you should always use try-with-resources statements...

Comment: I do but in fact I closed the same writer twice...

Comment: @TzL: See if you can fix the problem by adding an intermediary block which takes care of writing to the file. Please look into `synchronized` blocks to ensure that 1 thread will be writing to the file at any single point in time.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your class?